# Alternatives for sphinx gettext translation workflow?

Tags: translation, python-sphinx, gettext

Is there any other service than gettext that can build a translated document? I was thinking maybe there's an option for building from *-fr.rst or *-es.rst files that are placed directly in the source directories. This would also work for multiple images in different languages. Or is there a way with gettext to account for that?

Comment: @mzjn As mentioned, we might have pictures that need to be "translated" (recaptured" for the corresponding locale. Also we want to maybe exclude some parts of the documentation for certain languages.

Comment: @mzjn: different pictures and excluding modules for languages